# Safari CSS animation flashes on repeat only when height is large

Tags: css, animation, safari, css-animations

I'm trying to make an image slide by forever, like a marquee. In Safari, there is a white flash when the animation repeats, but only when the image height value is large. Try this code snippet. If you change `height` to something small (or if you use a different browser), the flash goes away.

The actual image I'm using on my site is a 215×80 gradient, stretched across the whole screen as a background.

```css
.image-bg {
  height: 10000px;
  animation: bg-slide 2s linear infinite;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/215/80);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
  width: 300%;
  
}

@keyframes bg-slide {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to { transform: translateX(-50%); }  
}
```

```html
<div class="image-bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by animating `background-position` instead (and doubling the value for some reason)

```css
.image-bg {
  height: 10000px;
  animation: bg-slide 2s linear infinite;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/215/80);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
  width: 400%;
}

@keyframes bg-slide {
  from { background-position: 0%; }
  to { background-position: -100%; }  
}
```

```html
<div class="image-bg"></div>
```